# WCF over WSDL Timeout error

Tags: wcf, xamarin, wireshark

I develop server-client app using Xamarin.
I use WCF to send data from server to client.
And sometimes happens timeout exceptions.

I guess this problem of slow connection to server.
Via fast Wi-Fi, 3g, 4g is no problems. But if connection speed is less then 3g, sometimes happens timeout.

I diagnose connection with WireShark, and it's saying next when timeout (see picture[image: picture])

Please, help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a binding you can specify timeouts and reader quotas. So you must raise timeout spans to an appropriate value. You can do it in code and through configuration file.

Through code you can do it like this

```
var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding()
            {
                OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
                ReaderQuotas = { MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647, MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647, MaxArrayLength = 2147483647 },
                MaxBufferSize = 6553500,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6553500
            };
```

And through configuration file you can do it like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="longTimeoutBinding"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="longTimeoutService"
      behaviorConfiguration="longTimeoutBehavior">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/longtimeout/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" />
    </service>
....
```

Comment: I tried to do this. But exception do not disappear.

Comment: In this line I have exception : `code`((MobileServiceClient)_mobileService).InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5);